# How start/stop/restart service as specific user and log this operation?

Tags: linux, shell, service, logic

I would like to execute my script, `/sbin/service storm start` as `storm_deployer` user.
So for this I create an user `storm_deployer` and add it into `/etc/sudoers`

```
hornet_deployer ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/sbin/service
```

And create this script `storm` in `/etc/init.d`

```
#!/bin/bash
#===================================================================================
#FILE: storm
#USAGE: storm [start] [stop] [status]
#DESCRIPTION: storm start, stop, restart service
#
#OPTIONS:
# REQUIREMENTS: ---
# BUGS: ---
# NOTES: ---
#
#AUTHOR: Valter Henrique, valter.silva@company.com
#COMPANY: company
#VERSION: 1.0
#CREATED: 03.27.13
#REVISION: 03.27.13
#===================================================================================
#
# chkconfig: 345 90 12
# description: storm start, stop, restart service
# processname: storm
#
# Get function from functions library
. /etc/init.d/functions

folder=/company/storm/bin #folder to the application
service="storm" #name of the service

startup=$folder/run.sh
shutdown=$folder/stop.sh
deployer=storm_deployer
process="63987524-22fc-4674-8896-11230716bc62"

#=== FUNCTION ================================================================
#
#NAME: start
# DESCRIPTION: Start the service storm
# PARAMETER 1: ---
#===============================================================================
start() {

  #----------------------------------------------------------------------
  # getting the process PID
  #----------------------------------------------------------------------
  pid_process=`ps -ef | grep $process | grep -v grep |awk -F' ' '{ print $2 }'`;

  if [ $pid_process ]; then
    echo "#######################"
    echo "$service is running!"
    echo "Stop then first!"
    echo "#######################"
  else
    action $"Starting $service: " su - $deployer -c $startup
    RETVAL=$?
  fi
}

#=== FUNCTION ================================================================
#
#NAME: stop
# DESCRIPTION: Stop the service storm
# PARAMETER 1: ---
#===============================================================================
stop() {

  #----------------------------------------------------------------------
  # getting the process PID
  #----------------------------------------------------------------------
  pid_process=`ps -ef | grep $process | grep -v grep |awk -F' ' '{ print $2 }'`;

  if [ $pid_process ]; then
    action $"Stopping $service: " su - $deployer -c $shutdown
    RETVAL=$?
  else
    echo "#######################"
    echo "$service is not running"
    echo "#######################"
  fi
}

#=== FUNCTION ================================================================
#
# NAME: status
# DESCRIPTION: Status of the service
# PARAMETER 1: ---
#===============================================================================
status() {

  #----------------------------------------------------------------------
  # getting the process PID
  #----------------------------------------------------------------------
  pid_process=`ps -ef | grep $process | grep -v grep |awk -F' ' '{ print $2 }'`;

 if [ $pid_process ]; then
    echo "#######################"
    echo "$service is RUNNING"
    echo "#######################"
  else
    echo "#######################"
    echo "$service is NOT RUNNING"
    echo "#######################"
  fi
}

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Main Logic
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
case "$1" in
  start)
        start
        ;;
  stop)
        stop
        ;;
  status)
        status
        ;;
  restart|reload|condrestart)
        stop
        start
        ;;
  *)
        echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|reload|status}"
        exit 1
esac
exit 0
```

So I log as user `storm_deployer` with `sudo su storm_deployer` and run the `/sbin/service hornet start` but keeps asking a password, everytime to run this service.

**update**

My /et/sudoers

```
## Sudoers allows particular users to run various commands as
## the root user, without needing the root password.
##
## Examples are provided at the bottom of the file for collections
## of related commands, which can then be delegated out to particular
## users or groups.
## 
## This file must be edited with the 'visudo' command.

## Host Aliases
## Groups of machines. You may prefer to use hostnames (perhap using 
## wildcards for entire domains) or IP addresses instead.
# Host_Alias     FILESERVERS = fs1, fs2
# Host_Alias     MAILSERVERS = smtp, smtp2

## User Aliases
## These aren't often necessary, as you can use regular groups
## (ie, from files, LDAP, NIS, etc) in this file - just use %groupname 
## rather than USERALIAS
# User_Alias ADMINS = jsmith, mikem


## Command Aliases
## These are groups of related commands...

## Networking
#Cmnd_Alias NETWORKING = /sbin/route, /sbin/ifconfig, /bin/ping, /sbin/dhclient, /usr/bin/net, /sbin/iptables, /usr/bin/rfcomm, /usr/bin/wvdial, /sbin/iwconfig, /sbin/mii-tool

## Installation and management of software
#Cmnd_Alias SOFTWARE = /bin/rpm, /usr/bin/up2date, /usr/bin/yum

## Services
#Cmnd_Alias SERVICES = /sbin/service, /sbin/chkconfig

## Updating the locate database
#Cmnd_Alias LOCATE = /usr/bin/updatedb

## Storage
#Cmnd_Alias STORAGE = /sbin/fdisk, /sbin/sfdisk, /sbin/parted, /sbin/partprobe, /bin/mount, /bin/umount

## Delegating permissions
#Cmnd_Alias DELEGATING = /usr/sbin/visudo, /bin/chown, /bin/chmod, /bin/chgrp 

## Processes
#Cmnd_Alias PROCESSES = /bin/nice, /bin/kill, /usr/bin/kill, /usr/bin/killall

## Drivers
#Cmnd_Alias DRIVERS = /sbin/modprobe

# Defaults specification

#
# Disable "ssh hostname sudo <cmd>", because it will show the password in clear. 
#         You have to run "ssh -t hostname sudo <cmd>".
#
#Defaults    requiretty
# 
# Refuse to run if unable to disable echo on the tty. This setting should also be
# changed in order to be able to use sudo without a tty. See requiretty above.
#
Defaults   !visiblepw

Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    env_keep = "COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE INPUTRC KDEDIR \
                        LS_COLORS MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME \
                        LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION \
                        LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC \
                        LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS \
                        _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY"

## Next comes the main part: which users can run what software on 
## which machines (the sudoers file can be shared between multiple
## systems).
## Syntax:
##
##      user    MACHINE=COMMANDS
##
## The COMMANDS section may have other options added to it.
##
## Allow root to run any commands anywhere 
root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL

User_Alias SUPERADMIN = %superadmin

SUPERADMIN ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
hornet_deployer ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/sbin/service

## Allows members of the 'sys' group to run networking, software, 
## service management apps and more.
# %sys ALL = NETWORKING, SOFTWARE, SERVICES, STORAGE, DELEGATING, PROCESSES, LOCATE, DRIVERS

## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
# %wheel        ALL=(ALL)       ALL

## Same thing without a password
# %wheel        ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL

## Allows members of the users group to mount and unmount the 
## cdrom as root
# %users  ALL=/sbin/mount /mnt/cdrom, /sbin/umount /mnt/cdrom

## Allows members of the users group to shutdown this system
# %users  localhost=/sbin/shutdown -h now
nagios ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/bin/touch, /bin/rm
User_Alias SUPERSUDOERS = %supersudoers
SUPERSUDOERS ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/tcpdump,/sbin/service,/usr/bin/kill,/usr/bin/killall,/usr/bin/iptraf
```

~

Comment: Why do you add `hornet_deployer` to sudoers if the user you want to give permissions is `storm_deployer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line in your sudoers file:

```
hornet_deployer ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/sbin/service
```

Is it after all other groups/users or like this (in between something)?

```
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
hornet_deployer ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/sbin/service
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```